# Nuxt 3 + Vue 3, micro frontend with vite-plugin-federation. Why 500 error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, micro-frontend

I have 2 applications, the first is on Vue (micro frontend module), the second is on nuxt(host app).

First application vite config:

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url"

import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation"
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"

export default defineConfig({
  preview: {
    port: 5005
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    federation({
      name: "app1",
      filename: "app1Remote.js",
      exposes: {
        "./App": "./src/App.vue"
      },
      shared: ["vue"]
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build: {
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
    target: "esnext"
  }
})
```

Nuxt app config:

```js
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      federation({
        name: 'host-app',
        remotes: {
          remote_app: `http://127.0.0.1:5005/assets/app1Remote.js`,
        },
        shared: ['vue']
      })
    ],
  }
})
```

Then, I start my first app on vue with `vite preview` command

And in the second application I get this error:

[image: nuxt application 500 error]

BUT, if I open http://127.0.0.1:5005/assets/app1Remote.js, i'll see app1Remote.js file

[image]